# Use third party Web Component within Astro

Tags: web-component, astrojs

I really want to use this switch component within astro:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.12.0/cdn/components/switch/switch.js

This file (if you click it) has a couple of imports "chunks".

I really want astro / vite to bundle this into the client-side javascript I don't want to depend on this externally. I want it to be bundled into the site.

I've tried a bunch of things to get this to work, including wrapping it in an astro file like this:

```
---
import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@shoelace-style/shoelace@2.12.0/cdn/components/switch/switch.js'
---
<sl-switch></sl-switch>
```

There is a tutorial on the Astro website about how to create a custom web component but none about how to use an external one.

https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/client-side-scripts/#web-components-with-custom-elements

I just want vite to bundle this esm module and include it within the site (on pages it's used)...

Answer (score 0):

If you want Vite to resolve CDN inline, you have to write a plugin for it. However, if you only have needs like this, adding a plugin is overkill:

You have npm:

```
---
import '@shoelace-style/shoelace/cdn/components/switch/switch.js'
---
<sl-switch></sl-switch>
```

Comment: 1) the cdn isn't in the package.json "exports" I think it would be "dist"
2) this doesn't work no component shows

Answer (score 0):

I found a repo here that does Astro + Shoelace and works:

https://github.com/gongfuio/new-astro-repo/blob/main/astro.config.mjs

It uses `viteStaticCopy`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config';
import react from "@astrojs/react";
import tailwind from "@astrojs/tailwind";
import mdx from "@astrojs/mdx";
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [react(), tailwind(), mdx()],
  vite: {
    plugins: [
      viteStaticCopy({
        targets: [
          {
            src: 'node_modules/@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/assets/**/*',
            dest: './shoelace/assets'
          }
        ]
      })
    ]
  }
});
```

then usage is:

```html
<script>
  import '@shoelace-style/shoelace/dist/components/switch/switch.js';
</script>
<sl-switch>Switch</sl-switch>
```